# Drawing Contours while removing smaller areas

Tags: c++, opencv, drawing, webcam, contour

I want to draw contour just around my hand in a live webcam feed. OpenCV is detecting many other contours due to noise, shadows etc when I used the following code.

```
    cv::findContours(fgmask,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    cv::drawContours(fgimg,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
```

I found the following code online to remove small insignificant areas.

```
cv::findContours(fgmask,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
    {

                    if(contours[i].size() < 10000 && contours[i].size() > 0)
            {

            int size=cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
            if(size>5000)
            {
                            //Draw contour
                            vector<vector<Point> > tcontours;
                            tcontours.push_back(contours[i]);
                            cv::drawContours(fgimg,tcontours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
                            }
                            }
            }
```

But it does not draw any contours at all. I put a cout statement after the *if(size>5000)* statement to see if this statement ever came true, and i got the the Cout output.
So then why no contours? Is there some problem with the push_back function or what?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you want to use `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` ?
2. `if(contours[i].size() < 10000 && contours[i].size() > 0)` is useless here
3. Temporary vector `vector<vector<Point> > tcontours;` doesn't make any sense either

Try:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(fgmask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

// draw contours:   
Mat newImg = Mat::zeros(fgmask.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (contourArea(contours[i]) > 5000)
        drawContours(newImg, contours, i, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0);
}
```

Comment: When I use your code, the drawContours with i as the 3rd argument is giving an unhandled exception. The error is: Assertion failed (0<=contourIdx && contourIdx < (int)last) in unknown function, file contours.cpp, line 1810

Comment: @vatsalasharma: There's no way how this code would provide `i` that would be out of `0; contours.size()` interval.